# Go: Prepend Content to Outputs from Top

Tags: go

In my go program, I need to run `top` to continuously monitoring a specific process.  But `top` does not give me the timestamp when each line is recorded.  I'm thinking about prepending it to the outputs my self:

```
top := exec.Command("top", "-p", pid)
r, w := os.Pipe()
top.Stdout = w
top.Start()
```

This way I can read the outputs from `r` at one end of the pipe.  I wonder how can I fire an action to get the current timestamp and prepend it to the output whenever there's a new line from `top.Stdout`?  I think it should be like a callback or Python's generator, but I'm not sure how to do it in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
func main() {
    for ln := range topMon(2543) {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339), ln)
    }
}

func topMon(pids ...int) <-chan string {
    ch := make(chan string, 1)
    top := exec.Command("top", "-b")
    for _, pid := range pids {
        top.Args = append(top.Args, "-p", strconv.Itoa(pid))
    }
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    go func() {
        sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for sc.Scan() {
            ch <- sc.Text()
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    top.Stdout = w
    top.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := top.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return ch
}
```

The channel usage is just an example, you can just return the rwader from the pipe directly.

Comment: It seems that `for` loop inside the goroutine runs forever?  If I have `top.Process.Signal(os.Kill)`, then how to stop that goroutine accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird `sc.Scan()` will return false since the reader will return `io.EOF` and it will exit.